# Changing video source from code behind does not change the video

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to crop a video into different parts in C# and its working fine. After cropping the video, I will display the same using  `<video></video>`.

Lets say for example I am cropping video ***1.mp4*** into four as ***1_1.mp4,1_2.mp4, 1_3.mp4,1_4.mp4***.

After cropping, all the four parts will be displayed from which user can again crop. 
for Example lets say video **1_1.mp4** was first cropped from **00:00:01** to **00:00:20**, now if user want to edit the duration of the same file from **00:00:05** to **00:00:10**, he can do so. Code behind will crop again from the original video and then save to **1_1.mp4**.

Till this point everything working as expected. But after editing the cropped video with new start and end time, view still displaying the old video, even though the cropped video is changed.

I have tried to refresh the browser, cleared the cache, but still the video remains same. if the browser or the tab closed and reopen the application, then the correct video will be available.

Why the video causing this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you figure this out, Sabith?

Answer (score 0):

When you change the video, you will need to `load` it again and then call the `play` method

```
let video = document.getElementById('video_id');

video.load();

video.play();
```

Comment: I have tried this one as well, but still nothing changed. Moreover after changing the video, page itself is reloading, and am using Razor syntax to display the video.